# How to send query parameter in proxy_pass in nginx

Tags: nginx, devops, query-string, proxypass

I have questions while using nginx's `proxy_pass`, I am trying to use the `proxy_pass` directive to do the following:

if the request is `http://example1.com/test?number=1` it should be proxied to `http://example2.com/test?number=1`

Can any one help me with this?

here is my configuration in inginx

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;

    server_name  example1.com;

        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        location /test {
        proxy_pass http://example2.com;
        }
}
```

Comment: Using simply the `proxy_pass http://example2.com;` directive would preserve both the URI and the query arguments.

Comment: @Ivan Shatsky I already tried this procedure but did not work
it seems the parameter is not passed to the proxied domain

Comment: It should work if you didn't do something that would prevent it within your configuration. Can you include your full config (without the private information) to your question?

Comment: @IvanShatsky please notice i added the configuration in the question

Comment: I don't understand your configuration effort, do you want to proxy only the requests starting with `/test`? What should happened with the other requests? Your current `proxy_set_headers` directives intended to send a request to some local backend, if you are trying to proxy requests to some other physical server they are only for bad, at least the `proxy_set_header Host $host;` one.

Comment: @Ala'aMezian are you using any regex in your `proxy_pass` directive? by default proxy_pass would forward query params, if you're using any regex or variable in your `proxy_pass` directive, try forming the url by yourself, e.g.: `proxy_pass http://example2.com$request_uri;`